# Can we run .vbs extension file through RAKE command?

Tags: ruby, rake

I want to run a excel macro file through RAKE.
I have already written a script in VBS but i want to run it through RAKE command.'
1. Can i do it?
2. If i can what is the code to run a file in .vbs format?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute VBS from Ruby, you might want to look at the answers here:

[Running VBS script with Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31619268/running-vbs-script-with-ruby)

(I do not want to suspect that you are mixing pears and bananas right away. I hope you understand that Rake is Ruby and it might not be the best idea to couple it with VBS. Unless you have to, though.)

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR HELP !

Comment: Can you tell me why it is not a good idea to couple vbs with ruby?

Answer (score 0):

One more thing though !

I am running the .vbs files through a BAT file because it is more convenient and easy. Now i have written a ruby script to run the BAT file. Can you provide me the syntax to run the ruby script by editing the RAKEfile.

If you did'nt get my question. you can mail me on 
shashank.gece@gmail.com